# ajax get anchor tag name

Tags: ajax, tags, anchor

i have a href like this:

```
<a href="images/prevFeb-1.jpg" name="day-1" onclick="swap(this); return false;">
  <img src="images/thumbFeb-1.jpg" width="50" height="50" alt="" title="thumbFeb-1.jpg" />
</a>
```

when the user clicks on a thumbnail, the images get swap.
i will like to get the href name upon on click.
and i will explode("-",$hrefName)
and like to get the value "1"

any ideas many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
function swap(element) {
  var name = element.attributes.getNamedItem("name").value;
  var nameValue = name.split('-')[1];
  // do something with it...
}
```

More about `getNamedItem()` here: http://www.w3schools.com/DOM/met_nodemap_getnameditem.asp

Comment: well, here is my original js, so i am not sure if adding your suggestion might do the trick but i will give it a try! 
<script type="text/javascript">
         function swap(image) {
             document.getElementById("main").src = image.href;
         }
      </script>

Comment: erm... you do know you can just do `var name= element.name`, right?

Comment: great, will try element.name; can i assign this to a php variable?

Comment: Well, you'd have to pass the `nameValue` in as the parameter to an AJAX request and have PHP read that into a variable from `$_GET`/`$_POST`, but yes.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the hyperlink name fixed then better use substring on the name of your link.

Comment: the link is not seen, and i dont want the link to be seen in the browser, currently link works fine, i only want the name of the href? any ideas?